# Using SqlDelight with Flow and also mapping Entities to a wrapper object

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight

I am using SqlDelight and Kotlin Multiplatform and am wondering if there is a way to map the returned record entities to a helper class before returning the Flow.

Here is normal usage:

```
val players: Flow<List<HockeyPlayer>> = 
  playerQueries.selectAll()
    .asFlow()
    .mapToList()
```

I want to do something like this:

```
val players: Flow<List<HockeyPlayer>> = 
  playerQueries.selectAll()
    .map { it.toOtherClass() }
    .asFlow()
    .mapToList()
```

Is there a way to do this? I'm a Kotlin n00b so I feel like I'm missing something obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectAll()` returns a `Query`, so any mapping of result entities needs to happen after the `asFlow()` extension, and the query needs to be executed, i.e. `executeAsList()` for fetching the updated result as list.

An example could look like this:

```
val players: Flow<List<HockeyPlayer>> = 
  playerQueries.selectAll()
    .map { it.toOtherClass() }
    .asFlow()
    .map { query ->
      query.executeAsList().map { it.toOtherClass() } 
    }
```